# mvc route cannot find conroller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am following through with plural sight video  messageboard app. it was working fine and suddenly routing is not finding the controller; i put break point on  maproute function and it gets hit but from there i get not found error; also another problem is that i cannot see the error page ( call stack\ stack trace\ the horrible yellow page) it appears for a fraction of a second and then disappears.

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

so please help me with both problems

Comment: forgot to say that other apps work fine. I am using visual  express 2013 for web

Comment: Can you post your complete routeConfig. Also is your routeConfig registered in the Application_Start event in Global.asax?  RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

Comment: public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

           /* routes.MapRoute(
                       name: "MyMessages",
                       url: "MyMessages",
                       defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Messages" }
                   );*/
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }

Comment: problem solved: it was authentication problem